# How do I make "contains" in android to disregard the capitalization of a letter?

Tags: android

I'm trying to write a basic AI that responds back to text.

However, in this code ;

```
    public void registermessage(View view) {
if (edittext.getText().toString().contains("hello")){

    test.setText("Hello, sir.");

} else{
    test.setText("It would be better off to say hello first, sir.");
}
```

Whenever I write Hello, it isn't registered as hello. I want to disable any filter for capitals in that edittext. How do I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: if (edittext.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("hello"))

Comment: I don't want an equality though, if the user types "hello bot" it should still be able to register. Isn't equals exact?

Comment: See [TextView's inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType), or use String#toUpperCase()

Answer (score 3):

You can use java.util.regex.Pattern with the CASE_INSENSITIVE :-

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(your_text), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("hello").find();
```

or You can use this:-

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(your_text, "hello");
```

Comment: org.apache.commons.lang3 is not in the Android SDK, so you would need to import it as a jar and hope that it works on Android

Answer (score 1):

```
String tmp = edittext.getText().toString();
tmp = tmp.toUpperCase();

if (tmp.contains("HELLO")) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead :

```
public void registermessage(View view) {
if (edittext.getText().toString().toLowerCase().contains("hello")){

    test.setText("Hello, sir.");

} else{
    test.setText("It would be better off to say hello first, sir.");
}
```

Comment: That's dangerous. Using `toLower()` on both strings is *not necessarily* the same thing as comparing in a case-insensitive way.